# Is Zabbix capable of forwarding messages to another Monitoring Platform like Icinga2 (Manager of Manager MOM Configuration)

Tags: nagios, zabbix, icinga2

I have worked with HP Openview/OMi in the past and I am new to the Nagios/Zabbix/Icinga2 frameworks.  I was wondering if Zabbix is capable of forwarding messages to another monitoring system such as Icinga2 in the same manner as a manager of manager (MOM) or competency center configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix gathers data and fires up [triggers](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/triggers/trigger) of various levels according to the defined expressions (ie: ping loss too high, cpu usage too high, service X unreachable).

You can configure Zabbix to react to triggers with [actions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/notifications/action): you can send a mail to a team, send notifications through telegram or sms, call a webhook or call a specific script to do actually anything you need.